# With Azure Dev Ops, is it possible to update the nuget package version when doing a manual Release?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I've been previously using AppVeyor for any/all my nuget package CI/CD pipeline. When I tag a repo in GitHub, the tag name is the version of the nuget package to be pushed up to NuGet.org.

I'm trying to do this with Azure DevOps. What's really different to how I'm doing things is that when a commit/PR occurs in Azure DevOps, the code is compiled there and then and the result package is stored as an Artifact. During this process, we don't know what the version of the nuget package will be.

Later on, we decide to push up the package, so we create a tag (eg. 1.0.0.0). But ... we're not sure:

- Where should we do this? We can do it in Azure DevOps Releases or in GitHub.
- The artifact has been made. Which includes the .dll which has the version already set (based on the build steps build-number).

Have people done stuff with nuget and Azure DevOps and have the ability to set the version when they do their manual *release* ?

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated the version is embedded in the dll's on build. So if you would like to create a version of your package that is tied to a give Tag you'll have to rebuild it.

An easy way to set this up is to simply rebuild the rev./branch that you want to promote to a certain version. You could even include creating the tag into that build (there are several marketplace extensions that provide this functionality i.e. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.git-tag-on-release-task&targetId=40fd72d6-e22e-47ed-ae29-510062ad84c8).

At this point you could chose to push the package to the target Nuget feed or do that in a separate release pipeline if you prefer that.